# D'où vient l'irrégularité de forme dans les pronoms : auquel, à laquelle, auxquels, auxquelles, duquel, de laquelle, desquels, desquelles ?

Tags: pronoms, orthographe, contractions

Je sais quand il faut utiliser ces pronoms.

Je me demande simplement pourquoi la forme féminine du singulier est différente ?
Quelle règle (phonétique, grammaticale) ou bien logique dicte cette particularité ?

Je pense que cette différence est due à la manque de forme contractée à+la/de+la mais il me faut la vérification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« Au » est la contraction de « à le », de même « de le » devient « du » alors qu'il n'y a pas de contraction pour le féminin « à la » et « de la ».

Comment: Oui et de même pour dudit / de ladite / desdits / desdites, et toute autre forme où l'article suit la préposition.